# rst mode in emacs on osx - cannot create pdf

Tags: emacs, elisp

Emacs: Gnu Emacs 23.4
OS: OS X 10.6
rst.el: not sure about version, but downloaded latest from [sourceforge](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/tools/editors/emacs/rst.el)

I have set the correct path in my .emacs so that it sees rst2pdf. I am trying to get the rst-compile-pdf-preview() to work on my rst-mode. When I do C-c C-c C-p, I have no idea what is going on - it fails silently. When I run this keypress, I want emacs to execute

```
rst2pdf "1 file with space.txt" -o "1 file with space.pdf"
```

Note that I need to have quotes to take care of files with spaces and the -o.

Here is the code is that is being called:

```
(defvar rst-pdf-program "/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview"
"Program used to preview PDF files.")

(defun rst-compile-pdf-preview ()
"Convert the document to a PDF file and launch a preview program."
(interactive)
(let* ((tmp-filename (make-temp-file "rst_el" nil ".pdf"))
 (command (format "%s %s %s && %s -o %s ; rm %s"
          (cadr (assq 'pdf rst-compile-toolsets))
          buffer-file-name tmp-filename
          rst-pdf-program tmp-filename tmp-filename)))
  (start-process-shell-command "rst-pdf-preview" nil command)
  ;; Note: you could also use (compile command) to view the compilation
  ;; output.
   ))
```

(sorry, I can seem to paste code with proper formatting, and I do not want to keep formatting each line individually).

Now, when I do C-c C-c C-c, and manually issue rst2pdf 1.txt - it works.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the rst.el that comes bundled with Emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's indeed a bug in this part of rst.el.  The `buffer-file-name` needs to be quoted, so replace `buffer-file-name` with `(shell-quote-argument buffer-file-name)`.  My rst2pdf also requires a `-o` whereas the rst.el code doesn't seem to provide any, but your sample code above added the `-o` much too "late": it should be placed between the second and the third `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the problem and found out that the external rst2pdf does not conform to reStructuredText calling standards. rst.el is correct in this regard and works with the rst2pdf found in the Docutils sandbox. IMHO the external rst2pdf should be fixed to conform to reStructuredText standards.

Apart from that adding a "-o" to the preview function won't fix the problem when generating PDF in general.

Stefan

Maintainer and main developer for rst.el